# C# Generics: Defining only one type as generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class which will wrap a dictionary to perform some operations on it. I am trying to instantiate it like:

```
class DescriptorList<K, Descriptor>
{
     <some code>
}
```

`Descriptor` is a class that I implemented but for some reason the compiler doesnt recognize that and thinks its a generic keyword (like 'T'). How do I make the compiler recognize my type.

Comment: Why do you need this as a generic type parameter if you know what it is in advance and will not change it from callers?

Comment: I want only the key type to be generic

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the key to be generic in your wrapping type, you don't need a type descriptor in your class declaration for the value.  You only need to specify the value type (Descriptor) when you're declaring the Dictionary instance you're wrapping.  For example:

```
class DescriptorList<K>
{
   private Dictionary<K, Descriptor> wrapped = new Dictionary<K, Descriptor>() ;

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your class like this, if you want to have dictionary with fixed type for values and vary type for keys.

```
class Descriptor
{}

class DescriptorList<K> : Dictionary<K, Descriptor>
{
     <some code>
}
```

or you can use this, if you want to have dictionary with fixed type for keys and vary type for values.

```
class Descriptor
{}

class DescriptorList<K> : Dictionary<Descriptor, K>
{
     <some code>
}
```

Comment: It may be what he wants (does he need a class derived from Descriptor or not?). Anyway +1 when you'll  provide some more detail instead a code snippet (oh by the way, he said DescriptorList is a _wrapper_ to a dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

> will *wrap* a dictionary

```
class DescriptorList<K>
{
   private readonly Dictionary<K, Descriptor> wrappedDictionary;

   //   <some code>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible with your current implementation. You may do the following (although it is just a workaround and depends on what you are trying to achive);

```
public class DescriptorList<K, V> where V : Descriptor
{        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, `Descriptor` here ***is*** just a generic parameter, like `T`. If you don't want it to be part of the generic, just use:

```
class DescriptiorList<K> { ... }
```